# Laravel - One To Many и вывод с сортировкой по количеству отношений

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Есть 2 таблицы: `categories` и `threads`. Как извлечь пять категорий, у которых больше всего тредов, используя **Eloquent**?

Например:

```php
Category::with('thread')->...
```

Сырой SQL запрос:

```sql
SELECT categories.name, COUNT(*) as amount
FROM threads
JOIN categories ON threads.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.name
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Таблица `categories`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица `threads`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function thread()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Thread extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'category_id', 'user_id', 'content', 'slug'
    ];

    protected $table = 'threads';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите подсчитать количество результатов из отношений, фактически не загружая их, вы можете использовать метод `withCount`, который добавить столбец `{relation}_count` к полученным моделям. Например, данный запрос:

```
Category::select([
    'categories.id',
    'categories.name',
  ])
  ->withCount('threads')
  ->orderBy('threads_count', 'desc')
  ->limit(5)
  ->get()
```

будет выглядеть так:

```
select `categories`.`id`, `categories`.`name`, (
    select count(*)
    from `threads`
    where `categories`.`id` = `threads`.`category_id`
  ) as `threads_count`
from `categories`
order by `threads_count` desc
limit 5
```

И вернёт коллекцию из `пяти категорий у которых больше всего тредов`.

---

**NB** Исправьте ошибку в модели Category `public function threads()`.